# Help me identify this Justice League audio cassette tape from my childhood

Tags: story-identification, justice-league

When I was in elementary school (1999-2004) I had an audio cassette tape featuring a Justice League story that I have since not been able to locate.

### Plot:

A macguffin that Darkseid wants is broken into several pieces which are scattered about Earth.  The Justice League breaks into teams of two to recover the pieces before Darkseid can claim them.  Each team successfully fights off Darkseid and retrieves their piece until the last fight where Darkseid overpowers Superman and Batman.  When they call in backup, Darkseid reveals that his plan was let the League gather the pieces and then take them from headquarters.  He does so, but the heroes chase him to his base and use the macguffin to banish itself to another dimension.  Then they retreat in victory.

### Locations I recall:

- Superman and Batman at Stonehenge
- Flash and Wonder Woman (I think) at the Great Wall of China
- Aquaman and Supergirl (I think) at an undersea volcano
- Superman and Batman (again) in Metropolis

### Quote I recall:

> **Superman**: I'll put Stonehenge back together and meet you in Metropolis

It bothers me that I haven't been able to locate the story considering how much detail I can recall.

Comment: Is this a video tape or an audio tape?  Was this a movie?  TV show?  Book?

Comment: @Brythan: Audio cassette tape

Comment: Was it in Podcast format or just audio of a video product? I mean, when you identified characters, did you guess it from conversation or the audio clearly told that?

Comment: Can this be *Justice League* S01E08? `Sorcerer Felix Faust threatens to keep Wonder Woman's home population transformed into stone if she does not gather artifacts for him.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Justice_League_episodes

Comment: @Discovery: I think it was more like a radio drama.  (Is that what you meant  by podcast format?).  I'm pretty sure it was meant to be listened to without visual accompaniment.  And it was only one cassette tape, front and back.

Comment: @Discovery:  And the villain was Darkseid.  I am 100% sure on that point.

Comment: [Any of these](http://www.thisoldtoy.com/l_fp_set/toy-pages/0-99/79-JusticeLea-storytp-book.html) look or sound familiar?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus - There was a Superman radio show from 1940-1951, could it be one of those episodes rereleased?

Comment: @Edlothiad: None of those.  From what I remember of the art, it looked more modern than those do.  It was a single tape in a [plastic cassette case](https://www.amazon.com/Music-Cassette-Clear-Plastic-magnet/dp/B06W9DKKX2/) with an illustrated cover.

Comment: @JohnP:  Possibly, but probably not.  I don't consume a great deal of superhero media, so I don't have a lot of context to compare it to, but it was definitely titled as a Justice League story, though.

Comment: Do [these tapes](https://m.ebay.com/itm/Batman-Superman-Justice-League-DC-Fisher-Price-Story-Books-Audio-Cassettes-/172856239411) look familiar?

Comment: @JohnP - Let's see... Not a Justice League header, not a Justice League header, villain isn't Darkseid, not a Justice League header.  Nope, nope, nope, aaaaand nope.

Comment: I don't suppose it might be one of the See & Read books? There was a trilogy released regarding Darkseid: https://onceuponageek.livejournal.com/335658.html

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: I can't watch the videos (and the alternate links don't seem to work) so I can't say for certain, but I think it's unlikely.  The images feature several heroes that I don't recognize, the art looks older than the crisp image I recall from the cassette tape cover, and the Moon was never a part of the story.  Also, the article only mentions VHS cassettes and records, and this was neither - it was an audio cassette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!  We found the cassette tape, and the case it came in.  It was

**[Total Justice: The Ultimate Weapon](https://www.allmusic.com/album/total-justice-the-ultimate-weapon-action-adventure-mw0000043268) (1998)**

> The evil Darkseid plans to build the Ultimate Weapon and destroy the
>   Earth — and it's up to the Justice League to stop him! In a race
>   against time, Superman, Batman, Wonder Woman, and other DC super
>   heroes travel around the world — to China, Egypt, England, even the
>   bottom of the ocean — to find the pieces of the Ultimate Weapon before
>   they fall into Darkseid's hands!
>
> This continues the line of DC Comics Audio Action Adventures — super
>   hero episodes that fuse all the action of a story with hot pop music!
>   Each track features a different location and its own musical style —
>   rock, funk, hip-hop, techno — in rich, wall-to-wall sound with 3-D
>   sound effects!

[image]

---

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the box cover and blurb from the rear of the insert.

Comment: As I recall, there was a Total Justice toy line in the 1990s - I believe this accounts for the ... unique appearance of some of the characters there.

Comment: @RDFozz Yeah, I listened to the tape again, and Batman gives each hero special armor and weapons for the fight.  As a child I couldn't recognize an ad campaign for an action figure line, but I can now!  :D